# How to fix predict.naive_bayes using no features for prediction in R

Tags: r, pca, predict, naivebayes

I have a data frame with 45045 variables and only 90 observations in R. I did a PCA to reduce the dimension and I'll use 14 principal components. I need do predictions and I wanna try to use the Naive Bayes method. I can't use the predict function with the trasformed data and i'm not understanding the error.

Here is some code:

```
data.pca <- prcomp(data)
```

I'll use 14 PCs:

```
newdata <- as.data.frame(data.pca$x[,1:14]) #dimension: 90x14
```

Training:

library(naivebayes)

```
mod.nb <- naive_bayes(label ~ newdata$PC1+...+newdata$PC14, data = NULL)
```

Tryna predict the 50th observation:

```
test.pca <- predict(data.pca, newdata = data[50,])

test.pca <- as.data.frame(test.pca)

test.pca <- test.pca[,1:14]

pred <- predict(mod.nb, test.pca)
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
predict.naive_bayes(): Only 0 feature(s) out of 14 defined in the naive_bayes object "mod.nb" are used for prediction.

predict.naive_bayes(): No feature in the newdata corresponds to probability tables in the object. Classification is done based on the prior probabilities
```

The vector of labels is a factor with levels 1 to 6, and for any observation that I try to predict the result is only 1. The 50th observation, for example, has the label 4.

Comment: You have not divided the data in train and test set. Another thing why are you putting `data = NULL`. It should be `data = newdata` in `naive_bayes` line. Use `pred <- predict(mod.nb, newdata)`.

Comment: Hi, when you want to use the formula interface then your `newdata` dataset should contain the variable `label` and 14 components. Then you can use following: `mod.nb <- naive_bayes(label ~ PC1+...+ PC14, data = newdata)` or even simpler `mod.nb <- naive_bayes(label ~ ., data = newdata)`.

Comment: For more examples how to use the `formula interface` or the `matrix/vector interface` please see the extended documentation: https://majkamichal.github.io/naivebayes/articles/naivebayes.html 

Best,
Michal

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I'd can use a vector of labels and columns separated, so I put data = NULL. When I take everything in a one data frame it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code modified from your code only

```
data.pca <- prcomp(data)

newdata <- as.data.frame(data.pca$x[,1:14])
library(naivebayes)

mod.nb <- naive_bayes(label ~ newdata$PC1+...+newdata$PC14, data = newdata)

test.pca <- predict(mod.nb, newdata = newdata[50,])
```